# Webbrowser select value from dynamic combobox

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to automate a form being filled out with the webbrowser control for VB.NET

The problem is that there is two comboboxes, the second having its values generated depending on the first one.
I can get the correct index to be selected for the first combobox, but for the second the values are never generated. I have to manually select another value for the first combobox and then the second is populated.

I have tried setting/removing focus of the first combobox to try and get the second to populate, but that has not worked.

My current code is:

```
''Select from the first combo box
Dim make As HtmlElement
make = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cars.carmake_s")
make.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 1)
WebBrowser1.Update()


''Should select the second value, but doesn't
Dim model As HtmlElement
model = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cars.carmake_s+cars.carmodel_s")
model.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", 2)
WebBrowser1.Update()
```

The HTML code that I am playing with is (cut down):

```
    <div class="form-row clearfix">
<label for="cars.carmake_s">
    Make<span class="orange">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="form-value">
    <div class="c-select-list c-slctbx-medium">
            <span class="c-icon c-icon-arrow-green-down"></span>
                <select id="cars.carmake_s" name="attributeMap[cars.carmake_s]" class="c-slctbx-depnode c-slctbx-medium" name="attributeMap[cars.carmake_s]"><option value="">Please choose</option>
                <option value="alpharomeo"
                                >
                            Alfa Romeo</option>

....
...
...                             
                    </select></div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-row clearfix">
<label for="cars.carmodel_s">
    Model<span class="orange">*</span>
    </label>
<div class="form-value">
    <div class="c-select-list c-slctbx-medium">
            <span class="c-icon c-icon-arrow-green-down"></span>
<!-->####This is the second combobox and gets populated depending on the first combobox<!-->
            <select id="cars.carmake_s+cars.carmodel_s" name="attributeMap[cars.carmodel_s]" class=" c-slctbx-medium" name="attributeMap[cars.carmodel_s]"><option value="">Please choose</option>
                </select></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

curElement.SetAttribute("Value", "Value You Want")

curElement.RaiseEvent("onchange")